# Google sheets api adding multiple rows

Tags: google-api, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-forms

I'm trying to figure this out and I must be overlooking something basic. (It took me WAAAY longer than it should have just to realize I hadn't added the trigger.)

When forms are submitted, if that page runs out of rows, it automatically expands. I have a reconciliation page where it is pulling the submitted data over line by line and analyzing it for discrepancies (the form collects billable time and tasks.)

So while the Form Responses 1 page will expand, I want to use a trigger on form submit to add a line to the reconciliation page and copy the formulas down. I can't seem to get the line to add though. Looking at the [google page](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/worksheets#modify_a_worksheets_title_and_size) for expanding the number of rows, I'm not sure what I am doing wrong there either but I THINK I need to add more java features to my computer.

If I simply copy and paste the example into a new sheet, most of the code is black instead of the standard editor colors. Saving pops up "Missing ; before statement. (line 1, file "Code")"
Line one is simply "import com.google.gdata.client.spreadsheet.*;"
So zerothly: Whats the most basic code I can use to add that blank row?
Then first: Do I need to import a bunch of stuff to get this (adding rows) to work?
Second: If so, and I transfer ownership of the sheet to someone, do they need to do the imports also?
Third: If so, and I want to do edits on another device, will I need to do imports there too?
Fourth: The example uses Update() but I can't seem to find an Update() function in javascript or googlesheets api documentation.

This is the code I am trying and variations commented out which doesn't seem to work:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
Logger.log('form submit triggered') 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var sss = sheet.getSheetByName('Reconciliation')
  var col2 = sss.getRange("B:B");
  var col2val = col2.getValues();
  var counter = 0;
  var sssrange = sss.getDataRange();

//  sss.Rows = sss.getLastRow() + 1 //Object does not allow properties to be added or changed if I uncomment - this seems to match the google example line though
Logger.log(sss.getLastRow());//=8
  var newsssrange = sssrange.offset(1,0); // didn't actually think this would work (since it also had the .update() part that previously didn't work for me) but came across it and was getting desparate.
//  sss.setRowCount(sss.getLastRow() + 1); // TypeError: Cannot find function setRowCount in object Sheet. 
Logger.log(sss.getLastRow()); //=8 
//  sss.Update();//TypeError: Cannot find function Update in object Sheet.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sigh... I am still wondering how to add more rows but I did answer my original need of adding a single line since form submits only add a single line. So I'm going to answer it since I had done so many searches and for some reason this never came up, maybe someone will find this useful if they are having the same issue.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var sss = sheet.getSheetByName('Reconciliation')
  sss.appendRow(['']);
}
```

Note that this adds a single blank line. If you run it a second time it won't add a second blank line as appendRow() adds after the last line with data. If you put a string in there or something and run it over and over you will get multiple lines.

I really would like to know about adding multiple lines though also since that will come up and I still seem to be missing something, probably obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Did you know that arrayformula woluld make new lines automatically.? If you paste this formula in Sheet2:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!A1,,,counta(Sheet1!A:A))
```

and then paste new values in Sheet1 range A:A, then new rows would be added on Sheet2.

Comment: Well that could definitely work. It grabs the data just fine. It didn't pull the formulas down though. Is there a way to do that also that I am over thinking?

Comment: I think, you could make all work with the help of arrayFormulas. There're many [examples in stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-spreadsheet%5D+arrayformula). For now you need is add a line to the reconciliation page and copy the formulas down. But ArrayFormulas can do almost any job with no need to pull formulas down. `OFFSET` is just for copy.